# Update/Insert to Meteor collection being ignored by server

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

I have a collection called "Materials" defined on the client and server.   In one template, I can insert and update correctly to Materials.   On another template,  I can insert and update but when I refresh the browser, the changes are lost.

The two views are called

view_materials (inserting/updating works)

view_orders (doesn't work)

Both templates have the materials collection binded to them like so:

```
//Bind viewOrders to Materials collection
Template.view_order.materials = function () {
return Materials.find();
};

// Bind materialsTemplate to Materials collection
Template.view_materials.materials = function () {
return Materials.find();
};
```

and both are using the function below to update.

```
var docid = Materials.findOne({material_number: newMaterial.material_number});
console.log(docid._id);
Materials.update({_id:docid._id},{$set: {material_qty: total}});
```

Please note that the ID printed out to the console matches perfectly.  Like I mentioned, on view_orders it updates for a moment on the client but not in another browser window nor does it persist after being reloaded from the server. On view_materials it works perfectly.  Any ideas?

I also deployed an example of the bug here:
http://upexmple.meteor.com/

and added the source to github:
https://github.com/stereochromatic/update_example

The relevant code can be found in client/views/view_materials/view_materials.js
and
client/views/view_orders/view_orders.js

To duplicate the error:

Click on inventory and under Raw Materials, type A for material number and -50 for quantity.  You will see it get updated correctly.  Now click on create release and under raw material type, select A and -50 for quantity.  You will see the correct info get printed to the console and you may also see the changes on inventory but upon refresh those changes are gone.
- show quoted text -

Comment: I didn't find any `allow` calls in your server code. Are you using the `insecure` package?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response.  I have yet to remove insecure or use allow/deny, publish/subscribe yet.  I am waiting to do that as a last step.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your Meteor Collections outside of the client directory. I usually put mine into a /lib folder, but defining collections on just the client side can cause issues.

So just move

```
Materials = new Meteor.Collection("materials");
```

and

```
MaterialsLog = new Meteor.Collection("materialsLog");
```

into a folder outside of the client/server folders.

Comment: This looked promising and makes sense but alas I'm getting the same result.

Comment: I had the same suspicion, but he is defining the collections in the same way on the server, too.

Comment: I tried adding the collections to a new file at /lib/models/Materials.js and commented out where I define them in server.js.   Same problem arises.

Comment: Interesting... Does your console tell you anything? On the server side, or the client side?

Comment: No errors or anything.  I'm outputting things to the console (like ._id) for debugging purposes but that's the strange part..  the id's are correct and find is working.  I'm retrieving the data its just not allowing me to write in more than one template.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error. I've done as you said, but the changes do not disappear for me upon refresh. I can even close the tab and reopen it, and the changes are still there.

Comment: Can't argue with that, the proof is right there on the page.. Now I'm even more baffled!

Comment: Check your browser settings. I recently spent an entire week chasing a phantom that turned out to be my browser setting for blocking third-party cookies. Make sure you are not disabling cache for this site, for instance. And try a different browser.

Comment: Thanks for checking this, I tried IE, Firefox and Chrome.. still scratching my head.  Made sure cache was enabled but no dice.

Comment: Hey Christian, which browser were you successful with?  Did you update using the console or form?  Thanks again

Comment: I used Chrome and just used the UI as intended (not the console).

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out...

I removed the autopublish package with

```
meteor remove autopublish
```

and then defined my permissions (and subscriptions) in /lib/Materials.js like so:

```
// Declare client materials collection
Materials = new Meteor.Collection("materials");

materials = Materials

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Meteor.subscribe('materials');


}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Meteor.publish('materials', function() {
        return materials.find();
});


materials.allow({

    insert: function (document) {
        return true;
    },
    update: function () {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return false;
    }

    });

}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped out.   I realize that for a production app this is best practice anyways so this needed really to be done at some point.   I originally was going to wait until the end to remove autopublish, insecure and wrap collection in publish/subscribe, allow/deny rules but this issue helped expedite that work :)

Comment: Just so you're aware, you should not define your allow functions in a js file that gets pushed to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code above my with file structure:
Please take note that I remove the `materials = Materials`

client folder:

**subscriber.js**

```
Meteor.subscribe('materials');
```

server folder

**publisher.js**

```
Meteor.publish('materials', function() {
    return Materials.find();
```

});

**allow.js**

```
Materials.allow({

insert: function (document) {
    return true;
},
update: function () {
    return true;
},
remove: function () {
    return false;
}

});
```

}

collection folder. this is outside from the client and the server folders

**collections.js**

```
Materials = new Meteor.Collection("materials");
```

let me know if its works and though this very late at least people can see it